# How many ignite server nodes are required to start if I have two managed server in a cluster and 50+ wars deployed on them?

Tags: weblogic, ignite

| ignite | 2.7.5      |
|weblogic| 14.1.1.0.0 |

Currently I am using ignite only for caching small amount of data which are frequently used and shared between all the deployments.

Answer (score 0):

Two may be enough (one per server node).

However, Apache Ignite does not have fine-grained access control feature. If you need to separate data access from these WARs, you may need to run a pair of server nodes per WAR, or maybe ensure that they only access Ignite through a common facade which restricts access.

Comment: let me elaborate more my situation. I have started 1 server node which is used as centralized point for accessing data from all wars. And from the wars separate ignite client nodes are getting started and connecting to the server node for retrieving and putting data in to cache.

Comment: Should work OK then. You need 1 server node per server VM.